# Make CSS Sprite Image resize accordingly as the broswer zoom is altered

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-sprites

I'm using css sprite and currently this is how it looks like [Icon is part of sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozOvZ.png)
It stays fine but when i start changing the zoom of the browser nearby image starts to bleed in the image
[Adjacent logo bleeding in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKnRl.png)
I tried increasing the padding by 100px as well but it is not a correct solution.

I need to ensure the sprite image stays in correct aspect and doesn't bleeds as the page is
zoomed.

I tried using a div wrapper but in this case it is not wroking.
here's the code

```
.icon {
    width: 512px;; height: 512px;;
    background-size: auto 70%;
    height: 70%;
    background-position: center center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
    /*zoom: 0.049;*/
    background: url("../resources/images/css_sprites_ico.png") 1px -3657px;
}
```

and the code where this is implemented is this

```
 {name:'setup',index:'setup',label:'Setup',width:80,align:"center",search:false,sortable:false,cellattr: function(rowId, cellValue, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                      var classes = "icon";
```